# ¿Como haría para conectarme desde el modelo a un servicio?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, mvc

¿Como haría para conectarme desde el modelo a un servicio que conecta con la base de datos En Mvc C#. El Servicio esta en VB? Los ejemplos que he visto en la web solo se conectan a la base de datos, pero en este caso quiero conectarme a un servicio que contiene los metodos para conectarme a la base de datos.

Comment: cuando dices servicio te refieres a un webapi, a un wcf, asmx, etc ? que tipo de servicio se trata? o el servicio es una clase

Comment: Un servicio WCF. Estoy buscando como hacer un login trayendome los datos del servicio y darle La autorizacion. (No se como hacer el login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los aspectos relativos al uso del patrón MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador), existe una clara separación de responsabilidades. La capa del modelo se encarga de gestionar lo referente a datos, lo que significa que en el proyecto que gestiona esta capa (Proyecto Biblioteca de Clases - DLL) debes agregar una referencia al servicio WCF, que no es más que una dirección URL que apunta a un servicio .SVC remoto. Usando Visual Studio, este se encargará automáticamente de crear las clases necesarias y la clase proxy que comunicará la capa de datos con el servicio remoto y viceversa. Asumo que ya conoces acerca de esto.

Ahora hay otro aspecto que es necesario que revises y es la gestión de autenticación y autorizaciones en MVC. Lo anterior se puede lograr mediante el uso del atributo [Authorize], [Authorize(Roles="...")] o [AllowAnonymous], el cual filtra el comportamiento del sitio a las peticiones del usuario de acuerdo a si está autenticado o no. Tu puedes filtrar, es decir, usar los anteriores filtros a nivel de controlador (Controller) o a nivel de acción (Action) individual para permitir o denegar su ejecución. Alternativamente puedes usar Request.IsAuthenticated para determinar si se ha gestionado algún mecanismo de autenticación. El uso de estos atributos requiere conocimiento de Filtros, para lo cual te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a los siguientes link para que te guies:

http://josemartinez.info/2015/05/11/filtros-en-asp-net-mvc/
https://jcavella.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/como-crear-sistema-de-login-con-mvc-4-razor-22/

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que un servicio es una clase que debes inyectar la implementacion en el controller, esto no se usa en ningun modelo

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection#Exercise1)

Nota: no encontre ejemplo en vb.net

En el controller defines un parametro donde inyectaras la implementacion del servicio

```
Public Class StoreController
    Inherits Controller

    Private service As IStoreService

    Public Sub New(service As IStoreService)
        Me.service = service
    End Sub

    'actions

End Class
```

Entonces defines una interfaz y la implementacion del servicio

```
Public Class StoreService
    Implements IStoreService
    'aqui implementas los metodos de la interfaz
End Class

Public Interface IStoreService
    'aqui metodos
End Interface
```

Al usar `Unity` registrs la implementacion del service

```
 container.RegisterType(Of IStoreService, StoreService)
```

en el ejemplo se uso Unity como framework de `IoC` pero peude usar otros como ser autofac, Ninject, etc

Comment: Una consulta, no seria mejor hacer una clase que se encargara de las conexiones a la base de datos? Por ejemplo en mi caso trabajo en MVC wcf y cree un namespace Helper que se encarga de hacer las conexiones  a la DB. No digo que su respuesta este mala, solo lo pregunto a tono personal

Comment: que es MVC wcf ? eso no existe. Los helper de acceso a la db son para hacer desastre, se deberia implementar el patron Repository, usando el objeto connection de ado.net en cada metodo implementando, o mejor si se usa entity framework

Comment: Perdon!, tipie mal era WCF, en wcf era mi consulta!

Comment: ahh ok puedes usar servicios remotos sin problema, aunque es bueno encapsular esa funcionalidad que peuda ser inyectable, asi podrias realizar test del codigo aunque no dispongas de los servicios. Es aqui donde interviene lo que comento en la respuesta

Comment: El problema es el siguiente, ya tengo el servicio todo los métodos en el servicio, pero quiero saber como autenticar un usuario, Entonces busco ejemplos en la web, y todas trabajan con el modelo. Discúlpenme pero soy nuevo en todo esto de MCV y C#.